# How to access disabled select option using Capybara and Selenium?

Tags: rspec, capybara

HTML:

```
<select id="expiration_month" class="javascript-only form-control input-lg pull-left valid">
</select>
<select id="expiration_month" disabled="" style="width:118px">

  <option selected="" value="01"></option>
  <option value="02"></option>
  ...
```

For some reason, the select is disabled.

I tried the following code in RSpec:

```
within 'select#expiration_month'[1] do
  select '01'
end
```

But got this cryptic error:

```
Failure/Error: within 'select#expiration_month'[1] do
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "e"
```

How to select an option?

Using Selenium (Firefox) driver.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
within '#the id of select' do
  find("option[value='01']").click
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`'select#expiration_month'` is an instance of `String` class.

`String` class has `#[]` method. So `'select#expiration_month'[1]` is `e` (second character of the string).

There's no `e` element on the page. So you get that error.

Probably you want to do:

```
find("#expiration_month option[value='01']").click
```